# Erro ao enviar requisição - get.

Tags: python, string

Considerando o código abaixo:

```
path = "/admin/"
host = "192.168.1.1"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, 80))

req = ("GET /"+path+" HTTP/1.1\n Host: %s \r\n\r\n", host)

s.send(req)
print(s.recv())
s.close()
```

Estou tentando enviar uma simples requisição `get` mas não estou conseguindo. Ao concatenar `tupla` com `string` obtenho a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> TypeError: must be string or path, not tuple

O que há de errado com este código?

Comment: Qual foi sua intenção de por `, host` nessa linha? Não entendi a intenção. `req = ("GET /"+path+" HTTP/1.1\n Host: %s \r\n\r\n", host)`

Comment: minha intencao adicionar a var host na minha %string

Comment: Não é assim, que funciona. Provavelmente você deve ter imaginado algo nessa linha: `req = "GET /"+path+" HTTP/1.1\n Host: "+host+" \r\n\r\n"` - de qq forma, a resposta dada deve resolver o problema.

Comment: entao eu sai confundindo tudo, e que meu teclado ta com defeito dai eu copiei esse trecho de codigo da net mas eu ja tinha estudado isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro deve acontecer na linha `s.send(req)` - o método socket.send espera uma string (ou um buffer, não um "path"  - será que você transcreveu a mensagem incorretamente?).

O que acontece é que na linha que você cria o conteúdo de `req` você não está formatando a string, e sim criando uma "tupla" - uma sequência de dois elementos separados por ","  -  a formatação de strings usando "%"  usa o operador  "%" entre a string e os parâmetros, e não uma chamada a função (ou algo parecido - que é o que você faz aí) - em que os parâmetros são separados por ",".

Ou seja, re-escreva a sua linha que define `req` para que seja:

```
req = "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\n Host: %s \r\n\r\n" % (path, host)
```

em vez de como está. A sintaxe de formatação de strings com "%" tem sido preterida nos últimos anos pela nova forma de formatar strings com o método "format": digita-se um pouco mais, mas é um pouco menos máigco para entender e ler - além de ter mais flexibilidade em casos avançados - nesse caso, sua linha seria assim (e você provavelemente não teria se confundido com a sintaxe como aconteceu):

```
req = "GET /{} HTTP/1.1\n Host: {} \r\n\r\n".format(path, host)
```

Perceba que nos dois casos, assim como o "host"  o "path" tambem pode ser passado como parâmetro apra formatação - a possibilidade de uma formatação de strings bastante flexível e rica de funcionalidades é um dos pontos fortes de Python - e quas e nunca há razões para se usar a concatenação de strings com "+"  só para interpolar valores, como você fez com  o `path` - vale a pena dar uma olhada na documentação do `format`: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Outra dica: além da mensagem de erro, ponha também uma indicação da linha onde o erro ocorreu - o interpreetador te diz qual foi.

Comment: agora saiu bonitinho mas uma vez obrigado era isso mesmo

Comment: e na funcao recv(#) # deve se colocar a quantidade de bytes que quer se recuperar e nao a reqisicao enviada eg recv(1024) eu errei so pra constar